# Is it necessary to create session in ecommerce

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I am developing a e-commerce web-application in JSP , it does not contain any kind of login or signup and now i want to add content in the cart..

do i really need to create a session to add the data in the cart?

Comment: Tags suggest you want to use a server-side solution. How do you plan to make the cart persist between page loads?

Comment: I think yes i need it,
because how does the server remember the user's previous choice?

and other idea??
to add content to cart?

Comment: sorry, i have not a good idea about how to add content to cart?

actually my cart is visible on the same page, where list of contents are available..
i think i should use javascript, to track users click and send those selected contents in the cart..

but on second click, the cart reloads and system forgets previous selection...please suggest me the right wayy..

Comment: The right way is using sessions. I thought you couldn't use them for some undisclosed reason :-?

Comment: Well... "do i really need to create a session" - Sounds like: "I don't want/cannot use sessions, can I get my cart with such restrictions?".

Comment: yes, actually i want the way, i am confused about using sessions..but if it is the efficient way then i will use it anyhow.. :)

Comment: Thanks Alvaro G. Vicario..

Answer (score 1):

Session is the way to go. It is the simplest mechanism which works and its a lot easier than achieving a similar effect manually.

As you mentioned, session is just a way to track the user. When you have ten customers on ten different machines accessing your page and adding things to their carts, you need a mechanism to keep track of which is whos cart.

This is how session works:

1. User opens you website for first time
2. Server checks the request for JSESSIONID cookie value
3. JSESSIONID is not present, hence server generates a random number
   and sets the JSESIONID cookie in the response the first time.
4. Server makes a note of this random number, created time and last
   request time from this user
5. Browser gets the page result, but also gets a JSESSIONID cookie
   along with the page response
6. Browser knows to "keep sending this cookie with every subsequent
   request"
7. So, for every subsequent user request, the browser itself sends this
   cookie with no effort from your part. This is the part that makes
   sessions easy.

Just try this simple experiment first:

```
<%
Integer thisUserReqCount = (Integer) session.getAttribute("reqCount");
if(thisUserReqCount==null) thisUserReqCount  = 1;
else thisUserReqCount++;
session.setAttribute("reqCount", thisUserReqCount);
%>

Request No: <%= thisUserReqCount %>
```

Here's a simple cart example:

```
<%
Map<String, Object> thisUsersCart = (Map<String, Object>) session.getAttribute("userCart");
if(thisUsersCart ==null){
   thisUsersCart = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   session.setAttribute("userCart", thisUsersCart);
}
//Now you have the cart thisUsersCart. You can do some thing with this to get data or put data in the cart.
%>
```